# get current playing song details from MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I am working on some project I have used this code but I want current playing music info as soon as I start my own app not after music state changed. Is there any way to get the **details** of current song played by Media Player?

```
package com.example.demomusic;

import java.io.File;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //public final static String START_REMOTE_CONTROLLER_ACTION = "com.example.demomusic.START_REMOTE_CONTROLLER";
    public static final String SERVICECMD = "com.android.music.musicservicecommand";



TextView tv;
String title, album, artist, genre, fecha, address, path, length;
Long duration;
File archivo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");

    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.meizu.media.music");


    String scheme = mAudioUri.getScheme();
    String title = "";
    String artist = "";
    if(scheme.equals("content")) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST};
        Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(mAudioUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE) != -1) {  
                title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            }
        }
    }


    registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /*String action = intent.getAction();
        String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
        Log.v("tag ", action + " / " + cmd);
        String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
        String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
        String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
        Log.v("tag", artist + ":" + album + ":" + track);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, track, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tv.setText("heyyy :" + track);*/


          Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            title = intent.getStringExtra("track");
            album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
            artist= intent.getStringExtra("artist");

            genre= intent.getStringExtra("genre");
            fecha= extra.getString("date");
            duration= (intent.getLongExtra(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION,1000));
            address = extra.getString("address");

            String all = "Title:"+ title +"\n Album:" + album + "\n Artist:" + artist + "\n Genre:" + genre
                    + "\n Fecha:" + fecha + "\n Duration:" + duration + "\n Address:" + address + "\n lenght:" + length + "\n Path:" + path;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, all, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tv.setText("hey "+ all);
    }
};

}
```